# InvalidArgumentError: Cannot serialize protocol buffer of type tensorflow.GraphDef

Tags: tensorflow

InvalidArgumentError: Cannot serialize protocol buffer of type tensorflow.GraphDef as the serialized size (2203200514bytes) would be larger than the limit (2147483647 bytes)

How to solve？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this thread points out, there is a limit of 2GB.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4291

If you'll be more specific about your problem, someone may give you a better advice on where to search.